# div template with 3 random size columns and bottom

Tags: css, templates, html

I use this template

```
<style>
    #block_center{
        position: absolute;
        right: 210px;
        left: 210px;
        text-align: left;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        overflow: auto;
        height: auto;
    }
    #block_right{
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        position: relative;
        right: 3px;     
        text-align: left;
        float: right;   
    }
    #block_left{
        position: relative;
        left: 3px;
        width: 200px;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        text-align: left;
        float: left;
    }        
    #block_content{
        clear: both;
        float: none;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        overflow-y:auto;
        overflow-x:auto;
        height: auto;
      /* margin-bottom: -50px; */
        margin: auto;

    }
    #block_buttom { 
        background-color: blue;
       /* z-index:  -10; */
        width: 100%;

        height: 50px;
        clear: both;
        }

    .clear {
        clear:both;
        overflow:hidden;
           }  

</style>

<div id="block_content">
    <div id="block_center"> ARTICLE <br> article_ajax_content </div>
    <div id="block_right"> Artile links </div>
    <div id="block_left"> banner </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="clear"></div>
<div id="block_buttom"> some text info about site and 31px height img </div>
```

Problem that I having is that Article not only can be random height size but also there is ajax block of random size content going after it and I simply can't absolutely stick bottom div to stay in bottom after all content regarding browser window size, content size, ajax block size...

Can any one help me with how css (I do not want to use jQuery to pin bottom block to a fix y coordinate) should look like for my pattern of use?

Answer (score 0):

Make all blocks relatively positioned and give the heights and widths using percentage rather than pixels.

Make sure the sum of all your height percentages is 100%(in case you want to cover the whole screen).

This ensures your page content covers the whole screen, irrespective of the screen resolution.

The relative sizes of each block is also kept the same across all resolutions.

**The key is to use PERCENTAGE values and not PIXEL values.**

To solve the Dynamic sized article data, just CSS the article div to have a scroll bar.

Comment: relative in block_center results with corrupt page (i want block_center to goes firs in html code, left and right should appear after it and in relation to it). Plus i want page to have normal scroll - not scroll in block_center or block_content. Right now problem - block_center changing height after page loaded and block_buttom does not follow it :( If i trying to use fixed position to block_buttom (which is sux by design) - i experiencing difficulties with setting any space after biggest block (block_buttom) and block_buttom goes upon it, covering peace of content :(

Comment: To summarize your requirements - 
Center block can take how much ever height it needs.
Left block and right block should be of the same height as the center block.
Bottom block should follow after these 3 blocks and cover the entire width available. This whole arrangement of blocks should have a single scroll-bar. Is that right?

Comment: Also I don't understand why you want to put the blocks Center, Right, Left; in that order. Left, Center, Right with relative positioning seems to be more logical. Right?

Comment: because in center there is main content and i want to put it higher in code, left block - less important of all - i want to put it as close to end as possible

Comment: The order in which you place the blocks **in the code** does not determine the importance of the block. It just determines the position. I strongly suggest you try out what I suggested in my previous comment.

Comment: preview in google with site:mysite.com look better - no crap from left block. problem with different resolution and window size i decided to fix with jquery - looks ok. Will it have some seo or usability (page does act better) effect - time will tell.

Answer (score 0):

this is currently does want i want

```
<style>
     #block_buttom { 
        margin-top: 10pt;
       /* z-index:  -10; */
        width: 100%;
        display: inline-block;
        height: auto;
        clear: both;
        }

    .page-buffer {
        padding-top: 50px inherit;
        height: 50px;
        clear: both;
        width: 100%;
    }      

    .clear {
        clear:both;
        font-size:0;
        overflow:hidden; 
           }  


#block_content {
    width:100%;
    text-align:center;
}

#block_left {
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    text-align: left;
    float:left;
    width: 10%;
    min-width:210px;
    height: auto;
    padding:  3px;
}

#block_center {
    text-align: left;
    display: inline-block;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:70%;
    min-width: 640px;
    height: auto;
    padding:  3px;
}

#block_right {
    position: relative;
    text-align: left;
    float:right;
    width: 10%;
    min-width:210px;
    height: auto;
    padding:  3px;
}

</style>
```

on high resolution it looking very nice, on lower - still require some tuning with finding balance of center block size and spaces between fixed size left\right blocks